# How to restore TOAD layout to its orginal layout?

Tags: toad

How to reset layout to orginal layout. I should get the same layout when first time I installed toad.

[image]

**@Edit-1:** - I dont see SQL editor in the red highlighted area. How we can bring that up ?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Option 1 - Reset docking layout and toolbars - Retain all option settings, saved connections, SQL Recall, etc.

Rt-click on Toad's toolbar and show the "Desktops" bar.

[image]

Restore your default desktop.

[image]

Reset your toolbar layout via rt-click menu over Toad's toolbar.

[image]

### Option 2 - Complete restoration of all configurations

If you'd like to do a complete restoration to a fresh installed state you can choose the "Copy User Settings..." menu item from the "Utilities" menu.

[image]

In there choose the option to reset to a clean state and click OK.

[image]

Note that this option will return all configuration settings to a fresh state including removing all saved connections and anything else you have done in Toad. The availability of "Copy User Settings..." is dependent on your version of Toad which I cannot tell from your screenshot alone, but it looks like you're on something in the 11.6-12.7 range so you should have it.

Comment: Could you please add screen shots that will really help beginner like me ?

Comment: Sorry, was away from PC with Toad on it. Edited, try that and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Many thanks for the nice info. Could you pls take a look at the Edit-1 above ?

Comment: That red area is on the right side of the Schema Browser. It is a different window from Toad's Editor. The Editor is available from the Database menu. See the Database|Editor menu item.